# JSF2 SessionBean to be initialized before page access

Tags: jsf-2

We are using JSF2 and Tomcat6. We need to initialize a session bean with backend values before the user access the first page.  May I know how to do this?

Comment: can you tell me more about what you're trying to accomplish? A SessionScoped bean is created for a new user session so it wouldn't exist before your user had started a session, but you could have an ApplicationScoped bean or another class which your SessionScoped bean can access. This of course depends on what you need to initialize.

Comment: We would like to initialize session bean with properties values common to all pages .So user can first load any page ,this session bean needs to be initialized to be accessible .

Comment: if the properties you want to initialize are global to all pages and users can you just use an ApplicationScoped bean instead of SessionScoped?

Comment: Also if you just need access to the bean on the user's first page view a SessionScoped bean works fine. You can just initialize properties in the Constructor and those properties will be available for the first page view.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to access common, session scoped data, from a page, you could

- write a session bean just for that data
- use that session bean in all pages that need access to this data; a page doesn't need to use only one bean, you could use some bean for most page specific data and one for common data
- use that session bean as a "managed property" (@ManagedProperty annotation in jsf2) in all beans that require access to this common data

Answer (score 0):

What you ask is strictly spoken not possible. A session is created exactly once a user does his first request. You can in general not create sessions in advance for users that have never requested any page on your server.

Any session scoped bean that is referenced from a page will be initialized during the first call to that page, and only during that first call. This is the best you can get.

(*If you actually mean a SessionBean and not a session scoped managed bean, then things are a little different. As you haven't used the EJB tag on your question I suppose it's the latter.)*